# "Approximating" ring of semi-invariants

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory, quivers

I'm trying to calculate the semi-invariant ring for certain types of quivers. For a very brief introduction to semi-invariant rings of quiver please have a look at this wikipedia article at the following [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-invariant_of_a_quiver)

I'm having trouble trying to understand the structure of the semi-invariant ring for the type of quiver I'm interested in. So, I have a very vague question which is-

> What are some other "closely related rings or algebraic objects" that I can calculate that would give me some useful idea about the original semi-invariant ring? Maybe some kind of resolution? Or, maybe some other ring that surjects onto the semi-invariant ring?